# Issue with vue when running npm prod

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, laravel-mix

Site works fine on local and dev server when using `npm run watch-poll`, however after using `npm run prod`, my site just displays a blank page and gives the following output in console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: 61 (at vue.js:1:91186)
at jl (vue.js:1:91186)
at hp (vue.js:1:135679)
at Array._p (vue.js:1:136054)
at Ya (vue.js:1:110358)
at vue.js:1:110762
at Ya (vue.js:1:110772)
at Za (vue.js:1:109727)
at Qu (vue.js:1:134032)
at vue.js:1:138722
at vue.js:1:138866
```

Reinstalled dependencies etc and still no luck.
No `<script>` tags in my id="app" as per solution:
https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/issues/3112#issuecomment-945651201

Has anyone else ever had a similar issue they fixed, or could help me out?

Thanks.

Versions:

vue 3.2.45

npm 8.15.0

Laravel Framework 9.52.16

PHP 8.1.25

Comment: You'll have better chance of debugging the root cause when running the app in dev environment (not necessarily the same as npm run dev).

Comment: Can you explain further please?

Comment: I mean Webpack should run in dev mode when you run `npm run prod`, this will make errors less cryptic. I don't know what is `npm run prod` in your case and how this needs to be done for Mix. Probably add `NODE_ENV=development` to .env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a simple case of running `npm install`.

Must have been an issue with a broken version of npm or something.